# Grid view is not appearing when im running my website

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

So i have a website hosted on blacknight.com. Im coding with cSharp and asp.net I have mySQL database stored within blacknight also.

However I want to add an admin section to my site where a user could log in and press a "load data" button and the registration table values from blacknight database would appear in a grid view.
However its just not working. Im wondering do I have to physically connect my gridview to my database? Because I have tried to connect to my hosted database with my gridview and it keeps saying it cant connect.
Below is the code behind my load data button. As as it stands when I upload my adminpages to blacknight and run, the gridview is not even appearing. This is my Fourth year project for college and I really need to get it working. Any help would be much appreciative.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring ="Server=xxxx; Database=xxxx; Uid=xxx; Pwd=xxx";

        MySqlConnection conDb1317466_bk = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        DataSet dbdataset = new DataSet();
        //binding.DataSource = this.bindingSource.DataSource;
        MySqlCommand cmdDb1317466_bk = new MySqlCommand("Select * from db1317466_bk.registration;", conDb1317466_bk);

        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDb1317466_bk;
            DataTable dbdataset1 = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            //DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;

            DataGridView1.DataBind();

            sda.Update(dbdataset);

        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "<script>alert('Can Load data');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the data source

Comment: Never ever put your password and credentials here like that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
GridView1.DataSource=dbdataset;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Instead of using

```
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
DataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Also, I don't think that you should use:

```
sda.Update(dbdataset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try
{
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmdDb1317466_bk;
        DataTable dt= new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        DataGridView1.DataBind();
}
```